# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS for NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsarray

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for an NSArray. There are other array and they are working fine. I initialized the array in viewDidLoad. I am getting the error whenever I am accessing it from different block. But this array is defined in header file. ARC is on. Here is my code

header file .h

```
@interface PopoverViewController : UITableViewController 
{ 
    NSArray *typeFilterItem; 
    NSArray *changeFilterItem; 
    NSArray *nFragmentFilterItems; 
}
```

.m File

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // set section
    typeFilterItem = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All",
                      @"Type-1",
                      @"Type-2",
                      @"Type-3", nil];
    changeFilterItem = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All",
                        @"Static Change",
                        @"Consistent Change",
                        @"Inconsistent Change", nil];


    nFragmentFilterItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Min",
                            @"Max", nil]; // this is the array causing problem
    NSLog(@"count: %d", nFragmentFilterItems.count); // here its ok
    // set filters
    [self setAllTypeFilers];
    [self setAllChangePatternFilters];

}
```

in uitable data source

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    /******* getting error at this line *****/
    NSLog(@"count: %d", nFragmentFilterItems.count);
    if (section == 0) {
        return typeFilterItem.count;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return changeFilterItem.count;
    } else if (section == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else if (section == 3) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the array defined in the header file?

Comment: When using ARC, the scope and retain behavior of the variable is defined in its declaration.

Comment: P.S. Search for EXC_BAD_ACCESS & NSArray for loads of suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If in your header file you have:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *nFragmentFilterItems;
```

you have to call:

```
self.nFragmentFilterItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Min", @"Max", nil];
```

Also you have to synthesize your properties in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize nFragmentFilterItems;
```

Comment: The synthesizing creates the appropriate setter/getter code. it should not affect the runtime. although the possibility of dropping the synthesizing statements was introduced earlier as an update of the llvm in xcode. but not sure what version.

Comment: Yes as @vikingosegundo said, the version of Xcode, since LLVM is bundled, will determine if `@synthesize` is needed. Also note that the OP is setting the instance variable directly and not the property.

Comment: Implicit syntheses only require a sufficiently up-to-date version of xcode (4.3, I think). It has nothing to do with the base or target OS.

Comment: Joe and Kevin, you definitely found the simpler and more elegant words :)

Comment: @Joe Yes i've seen, but since he has not posted the header, perhaps it could have been just a mistake. And sorry! yes, the autosynthesize has nothing to do with the iOS version, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: I simply declare the arrays. I didn't use @property/@synthesize.
`@interface PopoverViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *typeFilterItem;
    NSArray *changeFilterItem;
    NSArray *nFragmentFilterItems;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
nFragmentFilterItems = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Min",
                            @"Max", nil] retain];
```

Tks

Comment: I could do that @Tony. but, I want to find out the actual problem. Since, other arrays are working fine, there must have a solution. I will post it if i find one.

Comment: try to "call" other array in the "numberOfRowsInSection" section and you will have the same behavior..:)

Comment: try NSLog(@"count: %d", changeFilterItem.count).. lets say.. :)

Comment: they are working fine in the "numberOfRowsInSection" section except the `nFragmentFilterItems` array.